# Cloud Api Product Search asked for storing the images in the google cloud storage, but can i store them in the firebase storage as alternative?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-product-search

I'm using the Cloud Api product search, they ask me to store the images and the csv file  in the google cloud storage but i'm already using firebase in my project and my images stored there so can i choose firebase than the google cloud ?

Comment: Cloud Storage for Firebase is actually Google Cloud Storage: your Firebase projet is a Google Cloud project. I don’t know Cloud API product search but I imagine that you should be able to point to the Cloud Storage bucket of your Firebase/Google Cloud project.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes i know that firebase is for google, but i was wondering if it is possible to do that, anyway thanks for your help i'll tryi it now then,

Comment: Are you referring to the Vision API for product search? Were you using a specific guide from the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it as an alternative. As Renaud Tarnec commented, Firebase Storage underneath is Google Cloud Storage. This means that any bucket in your Firebase console is actually a regular Google Cloud Storage bucket.

You can confirm this by creating a Storage Bucket in the Firebase console and uploading objects to it (images for your dataset and the CSV file). If you access the Cloud Storage page in the GCP console, the same bucket and objects will be there.

As for using the Vision Product Search API with Firebase Storage, I followed this [quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/create-product-set-search-products), but edited the CSV file to point to images that were uploaded to the default Firebase Storage bucket (`PROJECT-ID.appspot.com`).

After letting the dataset images index, I was then able to send an image to be compared to the dataset as expected.

Keep in mind the service account you use to create a Vision API dataset must be able to [read Cloud Storage Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions) to access the images in your Firebase Storage bucket. Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help, I'm authenticating with an Api key not with service account because i didn't understand how to authenticate with service account when i'm send a http request from my flutter app, so when i made the bucket public in the google cloud everything works fine now, Do you recommend me to authenticate with service account rather than an api key ?

Comment: Can you explain more about how your Flutter app is used? Do users select local images to be compared against your dataset? In that case, you can pass images in the [request body encoded with base64](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/base64); that way, an API key is enough to run a product search, while not making your bucket containing the dataset images public nor using a service account. Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: yes indeed users select local images to be compared with my dataset, i'm using to call the api using the api key also, but my bucket is public i can't make it not public because an error will occur " cannot open file: ...... " when i made it public the error gone.